# Modal View with Navigation Controller's Bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

When I try to present a modalViewController, it covers up my navigation controller's navigation bar. Any tips? Thanks.

UPDATE (with code):

```
ComposeText *compText = [[ComposeText alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeText" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
compNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:compText];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:compNavController action:@selector(compDoneTapped:)];
compNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
[self presentModalViewController:compNavController animated:YES];
compText.title = @"Compose";
[doneButton release];
```

Everything seems to be in order, but the button is still not appearing on the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

That's what it is supposed to do. If you want a navigation bar, present a new UINavigationController modally and set it's root view controller to your modalViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The question you need to ask yourself is: "why do I want to show my navigationbar". If it is to give the user access to some buttons then it is the wrong reason. Modal view controllers are there to take full control of the screen and to not allow the user to manipulate anything else in the app until the controller is dismissed. If you don't want that do as Cyprian suggests and push a viewcontroller on your navigation stack.

If it is just a visual thing (logo ...) duplicate it in your modal view controller.

Comment: I need to show buttons that are essential to the navigation of the app--just a button to post content, and a cancel button. The presentModalViewController animation just seemed to make the most sense. Is there a better alternative besides just pushing a new view onto the nav controller's stack?

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController has it's own method to show another viewController.

```
-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

It uses stack, to push new viewController so it can handle its navigation with buttons.